# Anaconda Installer on Windows 10 doesn't result in proper way (no Navigator, no Prompt), how to fix it?

Tags: python, installation, anaconda3

I installed it on Windows 10 64x - from Anaconda site. It installs to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 and the folder is like:

[image]

When I run _conda.exe, the prompt window appears and closes in a second. That's all.
I don't see no Navigator, nor Prompt. I have rebooted the PC.

What's the matter and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to run that. Just use conda in shell.

Comment: conda does not work from shell with this installation. And all the same, Navigator and Prompt shoul be installed this way, but they dont.

Comment: should I add system variables with path to conda?